# Unity C# - Move character while jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character, move

My character moves great, and jumps great. But when jumping he just moves straight in the direction he came from and you can't rotate or move him while in the air. How can that be done?

From the Update Function:

```cs
if (controller.isGrounded)
{
    moveD = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    moveD = transform.TransformDirection(moveD.normalized) * speed;
    moveDA = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

    if (moveDA.magnitude > 0)
    {                 
        gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).LookAt(gameObject.transform.position + moveDA, Vector3.up);
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        moveD.y = jumpSpeed;
    }
}

moveD.y = moveD.y - (gravity * Time.deltaTime);
controller.Move(moveD * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: You need to separate your movement, rotation and jump logic. right now they're all together, and your answer is right there in the first line: if...isGrounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller.isGrounded` Is only true if the last time you called `controller.Move()` the bottom of the object's collider is touching a surface, so in your case once you jump, you cannot move until you hit the ground again.

You can solve this by separating your movement code and jumping code like so:

```
moveD = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
moveD = transform.TransformDirection(moveD.normalized) * speed;
moveDA = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

if (moveDA.magnitude > 0) 
{ 
  gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).LookAt(gameObject.transform.position + moveDA, Vector3.up);
}

if (controller.isGrounded)
{
  if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
  {
    moveD.y = jumpSpeed;
  }
}
moveD.y = moveD.y - (gravity * Time.deltaTime);
controller.Move(moveD * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - now that moving while jumping works, I need to use normalize so the character doesn't walk much faster when moving diagonally (ie. cap magnitude to <= 0). But when I use it it downscales the jump height to between 0 and 1, so be barely lifts off the ground.
Any thoughts? Can I only normalize the x and z axis somehow?

Comment: @JackNapier The code **JLum** posted here should do exactly that. Please take these questions to a new question so we can better discuss the code you have.